# Docker-compose started to fail without any changes made to the codebase

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose

I have a docker configuration that is running in Amazon EC2 cloud. As of today, when I run docker-compose up, it started to give this error:

`ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Same codebase, same config.

Any pointers to overcome this would be appreciated.

Comment: You should check if the image has changed recently. If you rebuild it, this may happen even if you didn't change your Dockerfile because the base image (FROM) may changed if the SHA256 is not used